# No answers deserve bounty

Tags: support, bounties

I posted a question a few days ago which I assigned a bounty to. One of the answerers didn't seem to have basically any idea what he was talking about and the other misread the question, so neither of them was any help. But I have to award the bounty, even though I feel that neither of the answers posted by other people (I solved the problem myself) are useful.

Is there any way that I can choose to not award the bounty?

Comment: Who says you *have* to award the bounty? The bounty may be *auto* awarded (if an answer qualifies) but you do *not* have to award it yourself.

Comment: I certainly do not have to award it, although if there is an answer with a score of (iirc) +2 or higher it will get half the bounty if you don't award any of them.

Comment: @Martijn: If I don't not award the bounty, it will be auto-awarded which I want to avoid.

Comment: @DeadMG: *half* the value is autoawarded. It is a consolation price. Is it that bad that it is going to be awarded?

Comment: @DeadMG: The bounty already did the work for you; the question received attention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters He's not asking for the bounty to be refunded, he just doesn't want it going to an answer that wasn't helpful.

Comment: @Servy: I know that, I just wonder why there is so much resentment for someone to get half the bounty.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It can indicate to future readers that the content is valuable when it isn't, and it can encourage users to go around to lots of bountied posts posting low quality answers, knowing that it's not good enough to really help the bounty awarder, in the hopes of getting this consolation prize.  Now as long as such answers aren't able to get 2+ upvotes the system works fine, but if people can get upvotes for poor or in some way insufficient answers then the system can't handle it.

Answer (score 10):

No, based on the current system in place, there is no way you can't have at least half the bounty awarded to a higher scoring answer.  To prevent even half the bounty being awarded,

1. Downvote the incorrect answer(s)
2. Provide a comment on the answer(s) explaining why they are not qualified answers.
3. cross your fingers that enough attention is paid to your question from the community for it to perform the disqualifying magic for you.

You've added a bounty to your question, which means it requires more attention; that means you need to give it more attention as well.  As the original poster of the question, your comments can potentially make or break the answers, therefore your participation is paramount.